# C# Treeview SelectedNode Click

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, nodes

I manually select my Node in Treeview:

```
treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes[0];
```

But I want to click it also, not only select, cause I load data from XML into Form, depended on which Node has been clicked..

How to do this clickevent on the specified Node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest trigger fetching data by [`SelectedNodeChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.selectednodechanged.aspx), not `onclick`, because may be user click on one node multiple times and every time should wait for fetching new data but in fact there isn't any changes in data, Also you should do functionality of fetching data in separate method not in events, in events you should just call them (kind of [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle):).

Comment: I think it is not available on WinForms, only in System.Web.UI.WebControls.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Saeed Amiri's answer, if you are using WinForms I think you need to add listeners to [`BeforeSelect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforeselect.aspx) or [`AfterSelect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterselect.aspx), instead of SelectedNodeChanged.